# Is there a way to get timezone without location info and how?

Tags: timezone

I know there're a lot services to give timezone given latitude and longitude. But is there a way to get the timezone for a device without providing location information?

Comment: What device? What APIs? In most operating systems you (the user) configure the timezone manually or (on smartphones) it's retrieved from the cellular provider.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp actually, it's a device without a full OS and it's connected to the internet.

Comment: There exist databases and services that determine location by IP and probably then you can use the service to get timezone by supposed location.